# How to run the timer tasks asynchronously?

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8

Hi am developing a windows phone 8 app using C# and xaml.
My previous team has developed some code, they have used many methods in timer control.
when it is updating all the methods are calling and its blocking the UI.
Is there any another way to use the timers asynchronously so that the UI can  not be blocked.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you should use the "xaml binding" to updating the UI

Answer (score 0):

There are several Timer classes in Windows Phone.

[`System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer(v=vs.105).aspx): runs on UI thread and makes UI unresponsive when executed.

[`System.Threading.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.threading.timer(v=vs.105).aspx): executes on a ThreadPool thread, therefore can not update UI directly. For an example how to make a cross-thread call to update UI, see the example in the link.

There is also a [`ThreadPoolTimer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.threading.threadpooltimer), seems it works like a `System.Threading.Timer` - runs on ThreadPool thread, just has different methods. But I have not used it.

So to answer your question, if a timer event blocks UI, then it is likely a `DispatcherTimer`, replace it with `System.Threading.Timer`, reference the code sample in the previous link.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the `DispatcherTimer`?

[How to Increment timer asynchronously ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21578147/)

Or else you could go with the `CountdownTimer`.

[How do you run a synchronous timer in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494861/)

as @kennyzx said there are many ways to do it, but the choice is yours.

[a sample on CountdownTimer from the Toolkit](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/building-a-windows-phone-countdown-timer-app-step-by-step)